# PYTHON3 (and not is PYTHON2 ) TypeError: Won't implicitly convert Unicode to bytes; use .encode()

Tags: unicode, transactions, byte, python-3.5, encode

l have this function that works perfectly with python2

```
 def writeCache(env, cache):
        with env.begin(write=True) as txn:
            for k, v in cache.items():
                txn.put(k, v)
```

However when l execute it with `python3.5.2` it returns the following error :

```
txn.put(k, v)
TypeError: Won't implicitly convert Unicode to bytes; use .encode()
```

First try to resolve that :

```
def writeCache(env, cache):
            with env.begin(write=True) as txn:
                for k, v in cache.items():
                    k.encode()
```

works but variable  v is not included.

```
def writeCache(env, cache):
                with env.begin(write=True) as txn:
                    for k, v in cache.items():
                        k.encode()
                        v.encode()
```

l get the following :

```
AttributeError: 'bytes' object has no attribute 'encode'
```

which is related to  `v.encode()`

Answer (score 7):

```
txn.put(str(k).encode(), str(v).encode())
```

that works for me.

Answer (score 0):

You don't really give a lot of information, but this is my best guess:

```
        for k, v in cache.items():
            txn.put(k.encode(), v)
```

Judging from the TypeError in the title, the `txn.put()` method wants to have bytes, but at least one of the arguments is a (unicode) string.

`v` apparently is a bytes object already (hence the AttributeError), so there's no need to encode it anymore.
But if `k.encode()` works, then it is most probably the offending (unicode) string, and encoding it should solve the issue.

Note that `str.encode()` uses `'utf-8'` by default.
It's not clear if the same default is used in Python 2, where the conversion is done implicitly.
I guess it depends on the library that you are using (the one where `txn.put()` comes from).